# Bootstrap show whitespace in rows/columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a situation in my web page where items in a row/columns setup (based on bootstrap) shows white space where it shouldn't. Please refer to this image:

[image: Unwanted white space at left]

It's a container div, with a row div and then a whole bunch of columns (to be exact: col-lg-4).

The vertical white space between 'Millenium Gold' and 'Midnight Oil' should not be there.

I don't think it's that important, but I build the page using React (i.e., Javascript).

I hope anyone can shed some light on this.

Thanks!

[Update]

Here's the console output for this page:

[image]

And this is my additional CSS:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 140% sans-serif;
}

input {
    font-size: 110%;
    outline: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
    color: #eee;
    background-color: #333;
}

.navbar-menu {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.search-bar-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.blend-item {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.blend-item-name {
}

.blend-item-descr {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.blend-item-roast {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.result-item {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.result-item h5 {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.result-item-content h2 {
    margin-top: -6px;
}

.result-item h2 small {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.result-item-content {
    background-color: #FFFAF0;
    outline: 1px solid rosybrown;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 30px;
}

.result-item-content hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rosybrown;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 0;
}

.result-item-content ul.list-inline li {
    color: rgba(6, 10, 26, 0.7);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    .search-bar-wrapper {
        min-width: 480px;
        width: 40%;
    }
}

.search-bar-field {
    position: relative;
}

.search-bar-input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.has-suggestions .search-bar-input {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.icon {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
}

.search-bar-clear {
    background-image: url(../public/img/cancel.svg);
    background-size: 25%;
    right: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.search-bar-submit {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    background-image: url(../public/img/search.svg);
    background-size: 35%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    opacity: .8;
    width: 40px;
}

.search-bar-submit:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.is-focused .search-bar-input,
.is-focused .search-bar-submit {
    border-color: #ccc;
}

.search-bar-suggestions {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}

.search-bar-suggestions li {
    cursor: default;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    padding: 12px 7px 12px 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.search-bar-suggestions li:last-child {
    border: none;
}

.search-bar-suggestions .highlighted {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.search-header {
    width: 100%;
}

.logo-home {
    margin-left: 72px;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
}
.logo ::after {
    clear: both;
}

.search-box {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.results-header {
    font-family: "serif";
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.results-header h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.results-body {
}

.results-box {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.results-box ::after {
    clear: both;
}

.cafe-box {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.cafe-info-beans {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.bean-box {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bean-image {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.imaginary-container {
    margin-top: 20%;
}

.leftimage {
    float:left;
}

.righttext {
    margin-left: 60px;
    float: none;
}

.righttext h2 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.hcenter {
    text-align: center;
}

.vcenter {
    min-height: 60%;  /* Fallback for vh unit */
    min-height: 60vh; /* You might also want to use
                        'height' property instead.

                        Note that for percentage values of
                        'height' or 'min-height' properties,
                        the 'height' of the parent element
                        should be specified explicitly.

                        In this case the parent of '.vertical-center'
                        is the <body> element */

    /* Make it a flex container */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    /* Align the bootstrap's container vertically */
    -webkit-box-align : center;
    -webkit-align-items : center;
    -moz-box-align : center;
    -ms-flex-align : center;
    align-items : center;

    /* In legacy web browsers such as Firefox 9
       we need to specify the width of the flex container */
    width: 100%;

    /* Also 'margin: 0 auto' doesn't have any effect on flex items in such web browsers
       hence the bootstrap's container won't be aligned to the center anymore.

       Therefore, we should use the following declarations to get it centered again */
    -webkit-box-pack : center;
    -moz-box-pack : center;
    -ms-flex-pack : center;
    -webkit-justify-content : center;
    justify-content : center;
}
```

Comment: Could we see the bootstrap file?

Comment: I'm using the bootstrap-3.3.7 npm module. You want me to post the entire CSS file, or is that not what you're asking?

Comment: Nevermind lol I thought you had edited it, but I realize those bootstrap files can be pretty large

Comment: It's not related to React, even though sometimes it can be. This particular problem is purely in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inevitable effect of `float: left` CSS property value that is engraved into every `col-•` classname of Bootstrap 3. See [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/bBJBaG), or just try this code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="big-and-tall"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="big-and-short"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="big-and-short"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="big-and-kinda-tall"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="big-and-short"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="big-and-short"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="big-and-kinda-tall"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.big-and-tall {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.big-and-short {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.big-and-kinda-tall {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

The problem is that "big-and-kinda-tall" element would like to fit somewhere under the "big-and-tall" but preceding element restricts topmost boundary of the former with its bottom line.

You could either put every triplet of cols into a separate row, or you could use Bootstrap 4 that relies on Flexbox rules: see [how it would look like in another Codepen](http://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/zoXoaE).

Comment: Your Codepen illustrates the problem very nicely. Here's a thought: what if I make each of the items the same height, enough so that the information always fits without enlarging the box?

Comment: Although my previous comment relies on the assumption that the information will never lead to a bigger enclosing box.

Comment: If all the cols are of equal height, they will form rows of three perfectly. You can play around with different hypotheses in Codepen and see how `float` makes the elements behave relative to each other. That's actually a lot of fun. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your columns are different heights and all inside a single row so you'll need to clear the float of the designated nth columns breakpoint and correct media query as well.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .blend-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .blend-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4 blend-item">
      <h1>ONE</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      <h4>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 blend-item">
      <h1>TWO</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      <h4>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 blend-item">
      <h1>THREE</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
      <h4>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 blend-item">
      <h1>FOUR</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
      <h4>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 blend-item">
      <h1>FIVE</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
      <h4>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 blend-item">
      <h1>SIX</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
      <h4>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 blend-item">
      <h1>SEVEN</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
      <h4>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</h4>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```